# Checkbox keeps returning true

Tags: php, jquery

I have a terms box on my register page, and I am sending that value to a php page where I check the value with the code;

```
'&terms=' + $("#terms").attr('checked')
```

and this is the html checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" data-validate="required"  />
```

In my php, I have tried multiple things, if it's set, if the value is equal to 1 and if it's empty yet my PHP code doesn't run, here's my PHP code:

```
        $termscheck = isset($_POST['terms']) ? '1' : '';
        if (!$termscheck == 1)
        {
            echo '
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                  <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <strong>Oh snap!</strong>Must accept terms of service
                  </div>
                  </div>';
            die;
        }
```

Even when the terms checkbox is and isn't checked that code never runs for some reason. How come?

Comment: Read the manual for jQuery[.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), that’ll tell you “how come”.

Comment: probably nicer to do it with jquery and not allowing page submit until terms checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('#terms').is(':checked'`) instead of `attr`

Answer (score 0):

when you use `&terms=`, then `isset($_POST['terms'])` will always return true.

try checking the value too:

```
isset($_POST['terms']) and $_POST['terms'] != ""
```

AND af course you are going to need to check if the box is checked as in **detailer**'s answer:

```
'&terms=' + $('#terms').is(':checked')
```